# Prevent window scrolling and then unbind after button click - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mousewheel

I'm trying to prevent scrolling of my site until a button is clicked and then allow scrolling. I can successfully prevent the scrolling but then I can't unbind this function. Here is my code:

Thanks in advance!

```
 $('body').addClass('noscroll');

 $('.fold-trigger').click(function(event) {
   $('body').removeClass('noscroll')
   console.log('removed');
 });


 if ($('body').hasClass('noscroll')){
  $(window).bind('scroll', function(){
    $('body').on({
    'mousewheel': function(e) {
        if (e.target.id == 'el') return;
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
      }
    })
  }); 
 } else {
  $('body').on({
  'mousewheel': function(e) {
      if (e.target.id == 'el') return;
      e.preventDefault(false);
      e.stopPropagation(false);
    }
  })
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your logic if you want to toggle this class on your body.

```
$('body').on('mousewheel', function(e) {
  if ($('body').hasClass('noscroll')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

Then add and remove `noscroll` class whenever you wish.